# Thread Safe decrement counter

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

**Problem**

In a project case I need to create multiple threads that are picking tasks from a queue and running them. Some of these tasks cannot run if a group of other tasks are still running. Consider something like file copy and defrag *(runs when system is idle)* in windows .

**Solution**

To implement this, I created a class based on 
[System.Threading.CountdownEvent](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CountdownEvent.cs).

Whenever a thread picks a blocking task from queue, they will `Increment` the `CounterEvent` and after they finished their job they will `Decrement` the `CounterEvent`.

If a thread picks a low priority task, it will `Wait` until `CounterEvent` is zero then starts running.

A low priority taks can immediately start with `Reset` of `CounterEvent`

Main thread or a parallel thread can monitor the status of lock by querying the `CurrentCount`.

**Here is the Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Threading;


public class CounterEvent : IDisposable {

    private volatile int m_currentCount;
    private volatile bool m_disposed;
    private ManualResetEventSlim m_event;

    // Gets the number of remaining signals required to set the event.
    public int CurrentCount {
        get {
            return m_currentCount;
        }
    }

    // Allocate a thin event, Create a latch in signaled state.
    public CounterEvent() {
        m_currentCount = 0;

        m_event = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        m_event.Set(); // 
    }

    // Decrements the counter. if counter is zero signals other threads to continue
    public void Decrement() {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        Contract.Assert(m_event != null);
        int newCount = 0;
        if (m_currentCount >= 0) {
            #pragma warning disable 0420
            newCount = Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_currentCount);
            #pragma warning restore 0420
        }
        if (newCount == 0) {
            m_event.Set();
        }
    }

    // increments the current count by one.
    public void Increment() {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        #pragma warning disable 0420
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_currentCount);
        #pragma warning restore 0420
    }

    // Resets the CurrentCount to the value of InitialCount.
    public void Reset() {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        m_currentCount = 0;
        m_event.Set();
    }

    // Blocks the current thread until the System.Threading.CounterEvent is set.
    public void Wait() {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        m_event.Wait();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an exception if the latch has been disposed.
    /// </summary>
    private void ThrowIfDisposed() {
        if (m_disposed) {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("CounterEvent");
        }
    }

    // According to MSDN this is not thread safe
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // According to MSDN Dispose() is not thread-safe.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            m_event.Dispose();
            m_disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

will this code work as expected?
Any flaws that I didn't see in it?
Is there any better option doing this?

**Note**

Application is written with System.Threading.Thread and cost of converting it for me is very high, however a great replacement solution always worth working on for future.

Comment: @Buddy It is not a good fit for Code Review with these questions: "will this code work as expected? Any flaws that I didn't see in it?" This code must be tested in order to be on Code Review.

Comment: @MannyMeng good to know.

Comment: Shouldn't `.Reset()` be threadsafe too?

Comment: @MannyMeng, I already tested this and it is working in my test environment, however as this code will run in a critical transaction environment, I want to be sure that it will not cause any interrupt. which looks like I missed a part as Muraad Nofal noted in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be one atomic operation and it is not threadsafe if you do it like this

```
if (m_currentCount >= 0) 
{
    newCount = Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_currentCount);
}
```

It may happen that `m_currentCount` is changed between the `if` and the `Interlocked.Decrement`
You should rewrite your logic to use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` I would also use `Interlocked.Exchange` in every place where you assign to `m_currentCount` then you don´t need `volatile` and the `pragma` You should also be aware of that under very heavy load it can happen that a reset event `Set` is getting lost